# JQuery and Serverside requiredfield validations can check both on click event

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, validation, webforms

Can I check both server side and custom jquery validations on click event ??

I have a function in js it returns true or false after validation .. 
I call it on onclientclick event when it returns true it simply postback skipping those require field validators validations ...  how to handle this other than that I do lot of code in js for all validations to move it in js and remove serverside tags ?

thats is the code

```
                $(".number-allowed").focusout(function () {                   

                        var sum = 0;
                        var stockValue = $('#tblQuantity tr:eq(' + ($(".number-allowed").index(this) + 1) + ') td:eq(' + 1 + ')').text();
                        var lblStatus = $('#tblQuantity tr:eq(' + ($(".number-allowed").index(this) + 1) + ') td:eq(' + 3 + ')');
                        var inputValue = $(this).val();
                        var totalQuantity = $('#txtQuantity').val();

                        $('.number-allowed').each(function () {
                            sum += Number($(this).val());
                        });

                        if (parseInt(inputValue) > parseInt(stockValue)) {
                            $(this).focus();
                            $(this).css("border-color", "red");
                            lblStatus.text("Value is greater than stock");
                            return;
                        }
                        else {
                            $(this).removeAttr("style");
                            lblStatus.text("");
                        }

                        if (parseInt(inputValue) > parseInt(totalQuantity)) {
                            $(this).focus();
                            $(this).css("border-color", "red");
                            lblStatus.text("Value is greater than quantity");
                            return;
                        }
                        else {
                            $(this).removeAttr("style");
                            lblStatus.text("");
                        }


                        if (parseInt(sum) > parseInt(totalQuantity)) {
                            $(this).focus();
                            $(this).css("border-color", "red");
                            lblStatus.text("Total value exceeds quantity");
                            return;
                        }
                        else {
                            $(this).removeAttr("style");
                            lblStatus.text("");
                        }
});
```

Comment: Post some code of what you did!!

Comment: @Guruprasad Rao check it i have updated my post

Comment: @RahulSingh thats not what im asking please check the post

Comment: @Mike - Where is you aspx Markup? Please share that as well.